# Extract Package Data from imported ssis package in SQL Server 2014 version

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I need to extract SSIS package data that is deployed in SSMS. Basically, I need to query the package definition from SSMS environment.

I queried in both `SSISDB.internal.packages` and `MSDB.DBO.sysssispackage`, but in SSISDB it displays NULL under package data columns and in MSDB I couldn't find the deployed packages at all.

Would someone give an idea where I can pull SSIS package data?

Answer (score 0):

Within the deployed SQL Server SSMS:

Integration Services Catalogs --> SSIDB --> Your folder --> Any Other Folders --> Projects -- > Your Package Name

Right click on Your Package Name and select Export